# Sklearn GridSearch with pre-training

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras, grid-search

I'm making a `Sklearn` `Pipeline` with a parameter optimization made by the `GridSearchCV`. The pipeline has to get the best model for several different entities implementing a **pre-train** and then **fine-tune** approach: **pre-train** all the entities together and the **fine-tune** every single element and returns a model for each entity. These are the constraint of the pipeline:

- Pre-train and fine-tuning have to be in the **same pipeline** because both the model has to have the same data in each GridSearchCV's fold.
- The pre-train model has to **pass its weights** to the fine-tuning model.

I have implemented:

- A Sklearn Transformer that takes a data-frame with all the entities in input and fit itself.
- A Sklearn Regressor that splits the data-frame in one data-frame for each entity and fit a Keras model for each entity.

What I'm missing is how to pass from the Pre-train transformer to the Fine-tuning transformer the weights obtained by the Pre-train transformer (considering that each GridSearchCV fold has different weights)

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
import copy

class MyRegressor(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, neurons, featInput, featOutput):
        self.neurons = neurons
        self.preTrain = None
        self.featInput = featInput
        self.featOutput = featOutput

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        X_train = X[self.featInput]
        y_train = X[self.featOutput]

        inputLayer = Input(shape=(len(self.featInput), ), name='INPUT')
        hidden = Dense(self.neurons, name='HIDDEN')(inputLayer)
        outputLayer = Dense(len(self.featOutput), name='OUTPUT')(hidden)

        self.model = Model(inputLayer, outputLayer)
        self.model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')

        if self.preTrain is not None:
            self.model.loadWeights(self.preTrain)

        self.model.fit(X_train, y_train)

        return self

    def predict(self, X):
        return self.model.predict(X[self.featInput])

    def transform(self, X):
        return X

    def score(self, X, y=None, sample_weight=None):
        y_true = X[self.featOutput]
        y_pred = self.predict(X)
        return mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)


class LoopTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, columns, component):
        self.columns = columns
        self.component = component
        self.components = []

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        for index, idx in X[self.columns].drop_duplicates().iterrows():
            entityDf = X[(X[self.columns] == idx).sum(axis=1) == len(self.columns)].copy()
            self.components.append({'id': idx, 'component': copy.deepcopy(self.component)})
            self.components[-1]['component'].fit(entityDf, y)
        return self

    def predict(self, X):
        results = []
        for comp in self.components:
            entityDf = X[(X[self.columns] == comp['id']).sum(axis=1) == len(self.columns)].copy()
            res = comp['component'].predict(entityDf)
            results.append(res)
        dfRes = pd.concat(results)
        return dfRes

    def score(self, X, y=None, sample_weight=None):
        results = []
        for comp in self.components:
            entityDf = X[(X[self.columns] == comp['id']).sum(axis=1) == len(self.columns)].copy()
            if len(entityDf) > 0:
                results.append(comp['component'].score(entityDf))
        return np.average(results)


#create the input dataframe: 3 entities
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['entityId', 'input', 'output'])
for entity in range(3):
    x = np.arange(random.randint(10, 20))
    y = x * (entity + 1)
    tempDf = pd.DataFrame(np.array([x, y]).T, columns=['input', 'output'])
    tempDf['entityId'] = entity
    dataFrame = pd.concat([dataFrame, tempDf], sort=False)
dataFrame = dataFrame.reset_index(drop=True)

#create the pipeline
neurons = [5, 10]
myPipe = Pipeline([('preTrain',
                    MyRegressor(neurons=neurons[0], featInput=['input'], featOutput=['output'])),
                   ('fineTuning',
                    LoopTransformer(['entityId'],
                                    MyRegressor(
                                        neurons=neurons[0],
                                        featInput=['input'],
                                        featOutput=['output'])))])

#pre-train and fine-tuning has to have always the same number of neurons
params = [{
    'preTrain__neurons': [neurons[0]],
    'fineTuning__component__neurons': [neurons[0]]
}, {
    'preTrain__neurons': [neurons[1]],
    'fineTuning__component__neurons': [neurons[1]]
}]

gs = GridSearchCV(myPipe, params, verbose=1, cv=3)

gs.fit(dataFrame, dataFrame)
score = gs.score(dataFrame, dataFrame)
print(score)
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far

Comment: @desertnaut I've added the code. However, I just don't know how to pass the `preTrain` weights to the `fineTuning`

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty the `sklearn.Pipeline` as is doesn't support this. But as long as you don't clone your pipeline (which happens for instance if you use a `GridSearchCV`), you can hack your way through with a code like the following code, which gives the instance of a step in the pipeline to the next step. You can apply the same principle in your pipeline:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin


class MyTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, scaler):
        self.scaler = scaler

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        print("got the means: %s" % self.scaler.mean_)
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X


X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
scaler = StandardScaler()
pipeline = make_pipeline(scaler,
                         MyTransformer(scaler),
                         LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs',
                                            multi_class='auto'))
pipeline = pipeline.fit(X, y)

X = X - 1
pipeline = pipeline.fit(X, y)
```

Which would give you this output, as expected:

```
got the means: [5.84333333 3.05733333 3.758      1.19933333]
got the means: [4.84333333 2.05733333 2.758      0.19933333]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm **not** talking about the sample weights but the actual weights of the neural network. Your approach is, however, feasible also in this case (extending the pandas DataFrame to contain also a Keras model) but I'm looking to an actual solution and not a workaround

Comment: I see, please note the updated answer then, I guess it kinda answers your question now.

Comment: yes, I know, but as you said, the `GridSearchCV` will make a deep copy of the scaler two times (one when copying the pipeline and one when copying `MyTransformer`) so as you will have an un-fitted scaler in `MyTransformer`